# How do I change the icon on a Chrome tab?

Tags: google-chrome, icons, browser-tabs

I have set up Chrome to always open the Gmail Offline app on startup so that I always have a synched version of my email when I'm offline.

However, I'd like the tab for the Gmail Offline to have the **blue** Gmail icon (see below) representing offline so as not to confuse it with the **red** icon in the next tab for my normal Gmail session.

I cannot seem to find an option to edit the tab label and icon in Chrome. Is there an easy way to do this?

[image: Offline Gmail icon]

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Tab Modifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-modifier/hcbgadmbdkiilgpifjgcakjehmafcjai/related?hl=en) extension and set the *icon* property in the json as described [here](https://github.com/sylouuu/chrome-tab-modifier/blob/master/README.md) to use the **blue** Gmail icon.

Comment: This extension also works in Microsoft Edge in Windows 10/11, which is not true in the general case for other Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get an image which I choose https://visualpharm.com/assets/783/Facebook%20Like-595b40b65ba036ed117d1f0f.svg

You switch the link this Is a code sample of how an icon is made `<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="http://www.newrafael.com/favicon.ico">` you change it to this `<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="https://visualpharm.com/assets/783/Facebook%20Like-595b40b65ba036ed117d1f0f.svg">`

Then that's how you change an icon . . . .Note: When you reload the page the icon will change to org